# Bootstrap button group colour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any way to set the colour of all my buttons in a button group at the btn-group level?

For example, I am grouping 10 buttons, and I want them to all be green (btn-success)

At the moment, I have to set the style on each individual button. I can set the size of all the button by setting btn-group-xs on the button group div, but it doesn't work with colour.

Ideally, I don't want to be setting the style of every button in a group and would like to set the style on the group div so all buttons within receive that style - In particular its just the btn-success as I want them to all be green.

Is there anything within bootstrap I am missing or am I going to have to do some custom CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no predefined class like `.btn-group-primary`.  The only way to address this within Bootstrap (currently) is to apply the colors as needed to the `.btn`.

That being said, you could do something simple with jQuery (since we're already using Bootstrap) to apply things a bit more automatically:

```js
$('.btn-group-primary .btn').addClass('btn-primary');
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-primary" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is more along the lines of where I thought I was going to have to go, cheers. A small part of me was hoping there might be something I had missed. Checking the v4 documentation it looks like its staying the same....shame

Answer (score -1):

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pu62oq3m/3/) without bootstrap.
working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pu62oq3m/4/) with bootstrap.

```
.btn-group button{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the answer within the scope of Bootstrap.

Comment: but it doesn't matter if you are working with bootstrap or not. You can still catch all buttons with their parent element. https://jsfiddle.net/pu62oq3m/3/ this is without bootstrap so check before you down vote

Comment: True, but there's more to think about. For example, if I set that style, you are correct, the buttons background colour would be green, but the buttons would still behave in a default way other than that - For example, hovering would change the background colour to light grey, the text on the button would stay black and be hard to read etc etc. Workable, but too fiddly for bootstrap and the simplicity of what I'm trying to achieve I think